# CSS: IE: white-space: nowrap not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, nowrap

IE not properly responding to **nowrap** CSS attribute.

Question: How do I make this work in IE so that it renders as Chrome's rendering result.

http://jsfiddle.net/subsari/tmz0t0z2/3/

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="long_string">Data 1 with long text</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
th {
border: 1px solid red;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.long_string {
    white-space: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    color: #FFA500;
}
```

How can I make IE render the table like Chrome does? Cleanest solution?

Thank you for your help ahead of time!

Comment: You should specify which version(s) of IE you are referring and *how* IE fails to do what you are asking for.

Comment: I have been struggling with IE10 recently and it seems to need the css rule `word-wrap: normal` to avoid wraping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not with `white-space: nowrap` (the text stays on one line) but with the `max-width` setting. Although it is generally [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh) even by IE 7, IE 7 seems to have an issue with it when applied to a table cell, as well as some other oddities. (My observations are based on using IE 11 in different emulation modes, not actually testing on older versions of IE.)

If supporting IE 7 (and older) is important enough, you might consider setting specific width on the content rather than maximum width. To would then need to wrap the long string in a container and set width on it rather than on the table cell. You additionally need to set `overflow: hidden` on that container (otherwise the overflowing content still makes the cell wider). Example:

```css
th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.long_string {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFA500;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="long_string">Data 1 with long text</div></td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This definitely worked! Thank you for the detailed explanation and clean solution--greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `white-space: nowrap` property should be fine to use in IE, going all the way back to 5.5

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/#browser-support

It may have something to do with the specific copy of IE that you're running. Try adding `!important` to the end of the `white-space: nowrap` declaration to make sure there's no plugins or user-agent style sheets that are conflicting with your code.

Comment: Jukka K. Korpela suggested that it is not an issue with white-space: but rather with max-width. Thanks though!